# Incompatible Pointer Type Error in Exploit C Code

Tags: c, exploit

I'm trying to compile the following exploit code for a learning exercise, and have done some research on pointers in C, but my numerous attempts to fix the code have had no effect on the compiler error message.  I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, I have next to no experience with C.

Relevant Error:

```
OFudge.c: In function ‘get_server_hello’:
OFudge.c:1009:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘d2i_X509’ from incompatible pointer
type [enabled by default]
```

Line 1009:

```
ssl->x509=d2i_X509(NULL,&p,(long)cert_length);
```

Entire Function:

```
void get_server_hello(ssl_conn* ssl)
{
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];
    unsigned char *p, *end;
    int len;
    int server_version, cert_length, cs_length, conn_id_length;
    int found;

    if (!(len = read_ssl_packet(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)))) {
        printf("Server error: %s\n", ssl_error(ntohs(*(uint16_t*)&buf[1])));
        exit(1);
    }
    if (len < 11) {
        printf("get_server_hello: Packet too short (len = %d)\n", len);
        exit(1);
    }

    p = buf;

    if (*(p++) != SSL2_MT_SERVER_HELLO) {
        printf("get_server_hello: Expected SSL2 MT SERVER HELLO, got %x\n", (int)p[-1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (*(p++) != 0) {
        printf("get_server_hello: SESSION-ID-HIT is not 0\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (*(p++) != 1) {
        printf("get_server_hello: CERTIFICATE-TYPE is not SSL CT X509 CERTIFICATE\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    n2s(p, server_version);
    if (server_version != 2) {
        printf("get_server_hello: Unsupported server version %d\n", server_version);
        exit(1);
    }

    n2s(p, cert_length);
    n2s(p, cs_length);
    n2s(p, conn_id_length);

    if (len != 11 + cert_length + cs_length + conn_id_length) {
        printf("get_server_hello: Malformed packet size\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read the server certificate */
    ssl->x509 = NULL;
    ssl->x509=d2i_X509(NULL,&p,(long)cert_length);
    if (ssl->x509 == NULL) {
        printf("get server hello: Cannot parse x509 certificate\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (cs_length % 3 != 0) {
        printf("get server hello: CIPHER-SPECS-LENGTH is not a multiple of 3\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    found = 0;
    for (end=p+cs_length; p < end; p += 3) {
        if ((p[0] == 0x01) && (p[1] == 0x00) && (p[2] == 0x80))
           found = 1;  /* SSL CK RC4 128 WITH MD5 */
    }

    if (!found) {
        printf("get server hello: Remote server does not support 128 bit RC4\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (conn_id_length > SSL2_MAX_CONNECTION_ID_LENGTH) {
        printf("get server hello: CONNECTION-ID-LENGTH is too long\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* The connection id is sent back to the server in the CLIENT FINISHED packet */
    ssl->conn_id_length = conn_id_length;
    memcpy(ssl->conn_id, p, conn_id_length);
}
```

Comment: Argument 2 is `&p`.  Since you have `unsigned char *p`, you are passing an `unsigned char **` (double pointer) to the function.  What is its prototype?  Does it take a single pointer?  If so, drop the `&` in the call.

Comment: This is just a warning, you should be able to compile..?

Comment: Exploits often work by using memory in nonstandard ways, so it's not surprising that it causes a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler clearly told you what the problem is. It even told you which argument caused the problem. Is that so difficult to simply compare the expected parameter type with the type you are passing as an argument?

According to this

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html

the function expects a `const unsigned char **` parameter

```
X509 *d2i_X509(X509 **px, const unsigned char **in, int len);
```

You are passing an `unsigned char **` instead. `const unsigned char **` and `unsigned char **` are two different types, not implicitly convertible to each other. So, here's your error.